# How to execute APIs after 30 seconds of time interval without waiting the response

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have to run a script for examination centre.

So the requirement is that the image APIs should hit after 30 seconds of time interval.

I have added loop controller, in that I have added a timer of 30 seconds.

But the problem is the image APIs response time is > 1 and we want to run next API after 30 seconds but currently next loop is executing after getting response from first API i.e 60 seconds

So is there a way that next API will hit after 30 seconds even if response of first API has not come yet?

But the problem is the image APIs response time is > 1 and we want to run next API after 30 seconds but currently next loop is executing after getting response from first API i.e 60 seconds

So is there a way that next API will hit after 30 seconds even if response of first API has not come yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about response times and other metrics you can just set the response timeout to 1000 ms under Advanced tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices), this way the setting will be propagated to all HTTP Request samplers in the HTTP Request Defaults [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules))

[image]